# Play2 does not find my implicit Reads or Format for JSON

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-json

This is my Search Object:

```
package models.helper
import play.api.libs.json.Format
import play.api.libs.json.JsValue
import play.api.libs.json.JsObject
import play.api.libs.json.JsString

case class Search (name: String, `type`:String){

  implicit object SearchFormat extends Format[Search] {
    def reads(json: JsValue): Search = Search(
      (json \ "name").as[String],
      (json \ "type").as[String]
    )

    def writes(s: Search): JsValue = JsObject(Seq(
        "name" -> JsString(s.name),
        "type" -> JsString(s.`type`)
    ))  
  }
}
```

I'm trying ot use this class when calling a webservice using WS:

```
val search = response.json.as[Search]
```

But the scala compiler keeps complaining on this line:

> No Json deserializer found for type models.helper.Search. Try to
>   implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type.

Could anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

- got the example from https://sites.google.com/site/play20zh/scala-developers/working-with-json
- this thread discusses the same issue but gives no solution, what example on what site? https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/WTZrmQi5XxY

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Indeed the example is wrong. You need your implicit `Format[Search]` value to be available in the implicit scope.

In your case the `Format[Search]` is defined as a nested value of the class `Search`, so you can reach it only from an instance of `Search`.

So, what you want to do is to define it in another place, where it could be referenced without having to create an instance of `Search`, e.g. in a `Formats` object:

```scala
object Formats {
  implicit SearchFormat extends Format[Search] {
    …
  }
}
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```scala
import Formats.SearchFormat
val search = response.json.as[Search]
```

You can also get rid of the *import tax* by defining the `Format[Search]` value in the companion object of the `Search` class. Indeed the Scala compiler automatically looks in companion objects of type parameters when it needs an implicit value of a given type:

```scala
case class Search(name: String, `type`: String)

object Search {
  implicit object SearchFormat extends Format[Search] {
    …
  }
}
```

Then you can use it without having to import it:

```scala
val search = response.json.as[Search]
```