# Acessing play template list item with index coming from javascript variable

Tags: javascript, playframework, playframework-2.2

I am new to playframework and to web programming, so the mixing of play variables, javascript and html is still a bit confusing for me.

In my case, I have a list of objects `alarms: List[Alarm]` coming from the controller of the view and I want to access one of the items of the list, but given that the `index` of the item come from a javascript function. Is that even possible?

I've tried the code below, but play's compiler do not understand the value of index in `@{alarms(index).Patient.name}`. Is there a way to do that? Or is it impossible because the list object is just used during the page creation and it cant be accessed later on by the javascript in a dynamic fashion.

```
@(alarms: List[Alarm], alarmForm: Form[Alarm]) 

@import helper._

@main("Alarm list") {

    <script id="showInfoScript" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function showInfoFromAlarm(index) {
       $("#patientName").text(@{alarms(index).Patient.name});
    };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, as the value of `index` will be resolved on client side and the value of `alarms` is only available when generating the `HTML` response to be sent to the client.

What you should do is to send the values under `alarms().Patient.name` to the client too and use JavaScript from there.

Comment: Id in fact need to access the whole object (and its sub-objects) in the javascript function. It seems that the standard way of doing would be to send a json object, but when I tried simply to do a `@Json.toJson(alarm)`, I got an error that there were no serializer and that Id need to **"implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type"**. Do you by chance have any idea what is the simplest way to pass the object?

Comment: Yes, that's normal, read more about this subject [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488950/play2-does-not-find-my-implicit-reads-or-format-for-json)

Comment: any idea how I can do that in java? I've just found solutions in scala for the serialization

Comment: No, sorry, I have never used Java for these things.

Comment: How complex is your `Alarms` class? Make sure you are using `play.libs.Json` and not the Scala version if your project is Java based.